# Get all products of a specific category only - without products of its child categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-collection

I want to get specific category product collection, not include it's child category product in it .

**Below code which i have tried**.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5);
 $getCollections = $category->getProductCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
         ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

can any one please help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5);
$isAnchorFlag = $category->getIsAnchor();
$category->setIsAnchor(false);
$getCollections = $category->getProductCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
         ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$category->setIsAnchor($isAnchorFlag);
```

Comment: @ Marius : thanks , your above code is helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this with a little twist with your code.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5);
/* Load all child categories  */
$child_cats = $category->getChildren();
$getCollections = $category->getProductCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => $child_cats));
```

Ref: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600354/product-collection-exclude-products-from-a-certain-category
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525419/get-child-categories-magento

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Your answer won't work. It will return strange results. You are getting a list of products and excluding some of them that have the ids the same as the child categories of the main category.

Comment: I think it's strange to include a product within a category AND it's child category at the same time. Just curious does it happen in reality?

Comment: You don't need to include the product in a child category also. It is done automatically if the category is marked as `is_anchor`.